# .net gridview column showing live calculation

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview which is pulling some data from a database. One of the columns shows an exchange rate, so 1.54 for example.  Above the gridview I have a text box that allows an amount to be entered, 500 for example.

I want to be able to have a column in the gridview that says '500 is' where 500 is taken from the textbox and then the row in the grid to show 500 * 1.54.

My textbox is:

```
<asp:TextBox id="CustomerAmount" runat="server" value="500" Width="73px"></asp:TextBox>
```

My gridview value I wish to multiply this by is:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" dataformatstring="{0:F4}">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#1686D6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />                  
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />                  
</asp:BoundField>
```

Any ideas, I'm stuck on this.

Comment: The site visitor will enter the amount and press 'submit' to cause a postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the header (suppose 1 is the column index):

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = CustomerAmount.Text + " is";
}
```

To set the cells data add a template column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="is">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="<%# int.Parse(CustomerAmount.Text) * (decimal)Eval("Rate") %>" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Make sure the textbox is not empty (has initial int value).

Comment: will try my rate field is                             <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" dataformatstring="{0:F4}">
                              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1686D6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />                  
                              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />                  
                            </asp:BoundField>
and my amount textbox is:  <asp:TextBox id="CustomerAmount" runat="server" value="500" Width="73px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: When I try this I get "The server tag is not well formed"